# Navbar is not re-rendering on router location change

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, connected-react-router

I want to display userName and changed the button text to 'logout' from 'login' in Navbar(nav component) when user is logged in. I tired to re-render the Nav Component by pushing the router history location to homepage on user logged in.

```
this.props.history.push('/')
```

Then User can successfully log in, user data is saved in localStorage and the router location is changed. data is saved in localStorage, but the component is not re-rendering.

Here is what I have tried.

1. tried to downgrade 'connected-react-router' to 'v6.0.0' but it threw me some errors. so put it back to the latest version '^6.4.0'.
2. tried to add Navbar code in App.js which is the parents component.
   But the app.js itself is not re-rendering either on user logged in.

### app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
/* --- Components --- */
import Nav from './src/components/nav';
import Loader from './src/shared/loader';
import './styles/main.scss';

const FlashMessagesContainer = Loader({
  loader: () =>
    import('./src/shared/flassMessagesContainer' /* webpackChunkName: 'FlashMessagesContainer' */),
});

const App = (props, { isOnModal }) => (
  <div id="app">
    <Nav />
    {!isOnModal && (
      <div className="flex justify-center">
        <FlashMessagesContainer />
      </div>
    )}
    {props.children}
  </div>
);

const mapPropsToState = state => ({
  isOnModal: state.modal.show,
});

export default connect(
  mapPropsToState,
  null,
)(App);
```

### nav.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

/* --- Components --- */
import {
  isLoggedIn,
  getCompanyName,
  clearLocalStorage,
} from '../../localStorage';

class Nav extends Component {

  handleUserLogout = async ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    await clearLocalStorage();
    return this.props.history.push('/login');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="nav">  
          {isLoggedIn() ? (
            <div className="flex">
              <p className="mr3 mt2">
                안녕하세요. <span className="b">{getCompanyName()}</span>
                &#8201;님,
              </p>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="login-btn td-none c-text br f-mini"
                onClick={this.handleUserLogout}
              >
                로그아웃
              </button>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <Link className="login-btn td-none c-text br f-mini" to="/login">
              로그인
            </Link>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Nav);
```

### localStorage.js

```
export const getToken = () => localStorage.token;
export const getCompanyName = () => localStorage.companyName;
export const isLoggedIn = () => !!localStorage.token;
export const saveUserNameAndToken = userData => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', userData.token);
  localStorage.setItem('companyName', userData.companyName);
};
export const clearLocalStorage = () => localStorage.clear();
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter as Router } from 'connected-react-router';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import configureStore, { history } from './store';
import Routes from './routes';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
 ...
});

const store = configureStore();
const root = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(root);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  root,
);
```

### routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { hot, setConfig } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
/* --- Components --- */
import App from './app';
import Loader from './src/shared/loader';

const Home = Loader({
  loader: () =>
    import('./src/components/home/homeContainer' /* webpackChunkName: 'Home' */),
});

...

const routes = props => (
  <div>
    <App history={props.history} />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" render={props => <Login {...props} />} />
      <Route path="/users/account" component={Users} />
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

const Routes =
  !module.hot || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? routes
    : hot(module)(routes);

export default withRouter(Routes);
```

I am expecting Nav component to be re-rendered when router location changes.

```
react: ^16.8.6
react-dom: ^16.8.6
react-loadable: ^5.5.0
react-redux: ^6.0.0
react-router-dom: ^4.3.1
redux: ^4.0.0
connected-react-router: ^6.4.0
```

Comment: 현재 <Nav /> 에서는 LocalStorage에서 값을 직접 불러오고 있기때문에, history 이동이 되었더라도, <Nav />가 리렌더링 되지 않습니다.

Comment: Are you persisting `isLoggedIn` inside your redux state?

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by saving 'isLoggedIn' state in redux store. And to persist the state from redux store on page refresh, I used 'redux-persist'.

Now Nav component is re-rendering on router location change and the userName data is saved even on page refresh.

### authReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
  userName: '',
};
const auth = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.USER_LOGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: true,
        userName: action.payload,
      };
    case types.USER_LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        userName: '',
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### nav.js

```
...
{this.props.isLoggedIn ? (
           ...
          ) : (
           ...
          )}
...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn,
  userName: state.auth.userName,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  userLogout: () => dispatch(userLogout()),
});

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
  )(Nav),
);
```

#### [ redux-persist SetUp ]

### store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import createRootReducer from './src/reducers';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
  persistConfig,
  createRootReducer(history), 
);

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(
      routerMiddleware(history), 
      thunkMiddleware,
      createLogger({
        predicate: () => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        collapsed: true,
      }),
    ),
  ),
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter as Router } from 'connected-react-router';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/lib/integration/react';
import store, { history, persistor } from './store';
import Routes from './routes';
import Loading from './src/shared/loading';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: { main: '#AE9A65' },
    secondary: { main: '#ee9105' },
    success: { main: '#43A047' },
    warning: { main: '#FFA000' },
    error: { main: '#ed4337' },
    info: { main: '#2196F3' },
  },
});

const root = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(root);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={<Loading />} persistor={persistor}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Routes />
        </Router>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  root,
);
```